# How to use the syntax and access values in custom data types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

I have a data type defined like:

```
data MyType a = MyType Weight [a]
```

and Weight is `type Weight = Integer.`

I don't exactly understand what is going on here. Is `MyType` comprising of an integer or `[a]`, or both?

In my case, I have gotten `MyType (a,b)`, and I want to know, is this a list of `(a,b)`, and if so, what syntax do I need to use in order to extract just the list of `a`?

Answer (score 3):

`MyType` is a type comprised by `Int` and `[a]`, so it has both. To extract the list from the type, you can use pattern matching:

```
getList :: MyType a -> [a]
getList (MyType _ a) = a
```

Alternatively, you can declare the type using [record syntax](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/traditional_record_syntax.html):

```
data MyType a = MyType { getWeight :: Weight, getList :: [a] }
```

which automatically generates the unpacking functions, so that `getList (MyType 2 [3,4]) == [3,4])`

Answer (score 1):

As you say,

```
data MyType a  =  MkMyType    Weight        [a]
     --------     --------    ------        ---
--   type         data        type of      type of
--              constructor   1st field    2nd field
```

defines a data type. Notice that I made one small alteration, writing `MkMyType` to the right of the `=` to differentiate it from the `MyType` on the left.

Now, for any specific `a`, `MyType a` is a *data* ***type*** -- it is a type of stuff that can appear on the right hand side of a definition.

*`MkMyType`* though (of type `Weight -> [a] -> MyType a`) is a *data constructor*. Applied to a `Weight`-type value, and a `[a]`-type value, it creates a ***value*** of type `MyType a`, which indeed holds on to two values at the same time -- a `Weight`-type value, and a `[a]`-type value, which were given to it at the time of its creation.

How this value is represented in the computer memory is not important. What is important is that we can *pattern match* on it like e.g.

```
foo :: MyType a        ->  (Weigth, [a])
foo (MkMyType  w     as)  =  (w, as)
    --------------------
--  pattern   1st    2nd
--           field  field
```

Notice that in the value `MkMyType w as` we have the value `w` of type `Weight` (we write: `w :: Weight`) and we also have `as` of type `[a]` -- with the same `a` as appears in the overall type.

Thus we can also define

```
bar :: MyType (a,b) -> (Weigth, [(b,a)])
bar (MkMyType w abs)  =  (w, [(b,a) | (a,b) <- abs])
```

and again, here we have `abs :: [(a,b)]` because the argument value's type is `MyType (a,b)` -- with the same `a` and `b`.

So if you only want to get the list of `a`s from the `abs`, you can write

```
baz :: MyType (a,b) -> [a]
baz (MkMyType _ abs)  =  takeFirsts abs
```

and here you need to implement

```
takeFirsts :: [(a,b)] -> [a]
takeFirsts abs  =  ...
```

which I leave for you to complete, as an exercise.