# How can I instantiate Functor for this data type?

Tags: haskell, functor

How Can I instantiate the following data types to be Functor ?

```
data LiftItOut f a = LiftItOut (f a)
data Parappa f g a = DaWrappa (f a) (g a)
data IgnoreOne f g a b = IgnoringSomething (f a) (g b)
data Notorious g o a t = Notorious (g o) (g a) (g t)
```

There are not very clear for the declaration themselves, inside the parantheses in the right member, is that function application (I ve never seen that, only basic type constructors)? I am new to haskell and I am just trying to understand the basics.

Comment: If `f` is `Maybe`, then `f a` is a `Maybe a`, so `f` has kind `Type -> Type`.

Comment: Have you tried using typed holes? `instance Functor (LiftItOut f) where fmap f (LiftItOut x) = _1` should give you a helpful message. (Note: you'll have to make a change beyond filling in that blank; follow the error messages.)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So that means f a is a classic (concrete) type ? Or, can f be "show" and a be 1 let's say?

Comment: @Johnny: `f a` is a concrete type yes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and let's say I have ```LiftItOut value``` aren't there more f's and more a's for which ``` f1 a1 = f2 a2```, how can I know it's type ? Sorry If the questions seem dumb but I am really new to haskell and trying to learn.

Comment: I mean, is the object ```LiftItOut 7 of type LiftItOut (+3) 4```, or where am I wrong ?

Comment: @Johnny The `f` and `a` in `data LiftItOut f a = ...` are types, not values. Without type system extensions, `f1 a1 = f2 a2` iff `f1 = f2` and `a1 = a2`.

Comment: voting to close

Comment: I hope you might find some of [my possibly relevant answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+type+constructor)  useful, in particular [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70306832/849891).

Answer (score 4):

Ask the compiler to show you how. Use the command line flag `-ddump-deriv`, enable the `DeriveFunctor` language extension, and put `deriving Functor` at the end of each type definition, and then the compiler will print Functor instances for each of them:

```
==================== Derived instances ====================
Derived class instances:
  instance GHC.Base.Functor g =>
           GHC.Base.Functor (Main.Notorious g o a) where
    GHC.Base.fmap f_aK1 (Main.Notorious a1_aK2 a2_aK3 a3_aK4)
      = Main.Notorious a1_aK2 a2_aK3 (GHC.Base.fmap f_aK1 a3_aK4)
    (GHC.Base.<$) z_aK5 (Main.Notorious a1_aK6 a2_aK7 a3_aK8)
      = Main.Notorious a1_aK6 a2_aK7 ((GHC.Base.<$) z_aK5 a3_aK8)
  
  instance forall k (f :: k -> *) (g :: * -> *) (a :: k).
           GHC.Base.Functor g =>
           GHC.Base.Functor (Main.IgnoreOne f g a) where
    GHC.Base.fmap f_aK9 (Main.IgnoringSomething a1_aKa a2_aKb)
      = Main.IgnoringSomething a1_aKa (GHC.Base.fmap f_aK9 a2_aKb)
    (GHC.Base.<$) z_aKc (Main.IgnoringSomething a1_aKd a2_aKe)
      = Main.IgnoringSomething a1_aKd ((GHC.Base.<$) z_aKc a2_aKe)
  
  instance (GHC.Base.Functor f, GHC.Base.Functor g) =>
           GHC.Base.Functor (Main.Parappa f g) where
    GHC.Base.fmap f_aKf (Main.DaWrappa a1_aKg a2_aKh)
      = Main.DaWrappa
          (GHC.Base.fmap f_aKf a1_aKg) (GHC.Base.fmap f_aKf a2_aKh)
    (GHC.Base.<$) z_aKi (Main.DaWrappa a1_aKj a2_aKk)
      = Main.DaWrappa
          ((GHC.Base.<$) z_aKi a1_aKj) ((GHC.Base.<$) z_aKi a2_aKk)
  
  instance GHC.Base.Functor f =>
           GHC.Base.Functor (Main.LiftItOut f) where
    GHC.Base.fmap f_aKl (Main.LiftItOut a1_aKm)
      = Main.LiftItOut (GHC.Base.fmap f_aKl a1_aKm)
    (GHC.Base.<$) z_aKn (Main.LiftItOut a1_aKo)
      = Main.LiftItOut ((GHC.Base.<$) z_aKn a1_aKo)
```

That's kind of messy-looking, but it's rather straightforward to clean up:

```
data LiftItOut f a = LiftItOut (f a)
instance Functor f => Functor (LiftItOut f) where
    fmap f (LiftItOut a) = LiftItOut (fmap f a)

data Parappa f g a = DaWrappa (f a) (g a)
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Parappa f g) where
    fmap f (DaWrappa a1 a2) = DaWrappa (fmap f a1) (fmap f a2)

data IgnoreOne f g a b = IgnoringSomething (f a) (g b)
instance Functor g => Functor (IgnoreOne f g a) where
    fmap f (IgnoringSomething a1 a2) = IgnoringSomething a1 (fmap f a2)

data Notorious g o a t = Notorious (g o) (g a) (g t)
instance Functor g => Functor (Notorious g o a) where
    fmap f (Notorious a1 a2 a3) = Notorious a1 a2 (fmap f a3)
```

Also worth noting that your `LiftItOut` is isomorphic to [`Ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap) and [`IdentityT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Identity.html#t:IdentityT), and your `Parappa` is isomorphic to [`Product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html#t:Product).

Comment: `-dsuppress-module-prefixes` will clean up `-ddump-deriv` quite effectively.

Comment: Also might be worth mentioning that `LiftItOut` should *probably* be a `newtype`.

Comment: Why do you delete the `<$` definitions, by the way? Those matter for these types!

Comment: @dfeuer Aren't they just important for performance, rather than for correctness? This seems like enough a newbie question that the extra complexity of explaining them doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: I suppose that's reasonable.

Comment: A `newtype` has the advantage that also `Applicative` and `Monad` can be derived, in addition to `Functor`.

Comment: this isn't really helping someone who's "new to haskell" and is "just trying to understand the basics", to _understand_ the _basics_.

Answer (score 0):

A *functor* `f` is a type constructor with an associated function `fmap` that from a function of type `(a -> b)` creates a function of type `(f a) -> (f b)` which applies it *"on the inside"*: <sup>(the parentheses are redundant and are used for clarity/emphasis only)</sup>

```
fmap :: (Functor f) => (  a  ->    b) 
                    -> (f a) -> (f b)       

-- i.e.           g ::    a  ->    b        -- from this
--           --------------------------
--           fmap g :: (f a) -> (f b)       -- we get this
```

(read it "*`fmap`* of *`g`* from *`a`* to *`b`* goes from *`f a`* to *`f b`*").

Put differently, something being a "Functor" means that it can be substituted for `f` in

```
fmap id (x :: f a)  =  x
(fmap g . fmap h)   =  fmap (g . h)
```

so that the expressions involved make sense (i.e. are well formed, i.e. have a type), *and, importantly,* the above equations hold -- they are in fact the two *"Functor laws"*.

---

You have

```
data  LiftItOut h a  =  MkLiftItOut    (h a)       -- "Mk..." for "Make..."
      -------------     -----------    ------
      new type,         data           type of the data constructor's
      defined here       constructor    one argument (one field)
```

This means `h a` is a type of *a thing* which can serve as an argument to `MkLiftItOut`. For example, `Maybe Int` (i.e. `h ~ Maybe` and `a ~ Int`), `[(Float,String)]` (i.e. `h ~ []` and `a ~ (Float,String)`), etc.

`h`, `a` are type variables -- meaning, they can be replaced by any specific type so that the whole syntactic expressions make sense.

These syntactic expressions include `MkLiftItOut x` which is a thing of type `LiftItOut h a` provided `x` is a thing of type `h a`; `LiftItOut h a` which is a type; `h a` which is a type of a thing which can appear as an argument to `MkLiftItOut`. Thus we can have in our programs

```
v1 = MkLiftItOut ([1,2,3]   :: []    Int   )  ::  LiftItOut  []    Int
v2 = MkLiftItOut ((Just "") :: Maybe String)  ::  LiftItOut  Maybe String
v3 = MkLiftItOut (Nothing   :: Maybe ()    )  ::  LiftItOut  Maybe ()
.....
```

etc. Then we have

```
ghci> :i Functor
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (<$) :: a -> f b -> f a
..........
```

This means that `Functor f => (f a)` is a type of a thing which a variable can reference, e.g.

```
                 -- f        a
v4  = Just 4     :: Maybe   Int
v41 =      4     ::         Int

v5  = [4.4, 5.5] :: []      Float
v51 =  4.4       ::         Float
v52 =       5.5  ::         Float

v6  = (1,"a")    :: ((,) Int)  String  -- or simpler, `(Int, String)`
v61 =    "a"     ::            String

v7  = (\x -> 7)  :: ((->) Int) Int     -- or simpler, `Int -> Int`
```

Here `a` is a type of a thing, `f a` is a type of a thing, `f` is a type which, when given a type of a thing, becomes a type of a thing; etc. There's no thing which can be referenced by a variable which would have the type `f` on its own.

All the above `f`s are instances of the `Functor` typeclass. This means that somewhere in the libraries there are definitions of

```
instance Functor Maybe   where ....
instance Functor []      where ....
instance Functor ((,) a)  where ....
instance Functor ((->) r) where ....
```

Notice we always have the `f`, and the `a`. `f` in particular can be made of more than one constituents, but `a` is always some *one* type.

Thus in this case we must have

```
instance Functor (LiftItOut h) where ....
```

(...*why?* do convince yourself in this; see how all the above statements apply and are correct)

Then the actual definition must be

```
   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> f           a -> f           b
   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> LiftItOut h a -> LiftItOut h b
   fmap       g       (MkLiftItOut  x )  =  (MkLiftItOut  y )
     where
     y = ....
```

In particular, we'll have

```
    --     g :: a -> b     --   x :: (h a)     --   y :: (h b)
```

and we don't even know what the `h` is.

How can we solve this? How can we construct an `h b`-type of thing from an `h a`-type of thing when we don't even know anything about `h`, `a`, nor `b`?

We can't.

But what if we knew that `h` is also a `Functor`?

```
instance (Functor h) => Functor (LiftItOut h) where
   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f           a) -> (f           b)
   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (LiftItOut h a) -> (LiftItOut h b)
   fmap       g       (MkLiftItOut  x )  =  (MkLiftItOut  y )
     where
     -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (h a) -> (h b)
     y = ....
```

Hopefully you can finish this up. And also do the other types in your question as well. If not, post a new question for the *one* type with which you might have any further problems.